# How to update two related tables with limit?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables which both have column *acc_manager* and would like to update both tables where the value for *acc_manager* is 34 to be 68 *but* I only wish for half of the values of my *client* table to be updated including related data in my *company* table.

In my example tables below, there are discrepancies such as a company having an account manager but a client of the same company may have a different account manager.

```
client
id  name   companyid  acc_manager
1   name1  1          12
2   name2  2          23
3   name3  2          34
4   name4  3          34
5   name5  3          34
6   name6  4          34
7   name7  5          12
8   name8  4          34
9   name9  6          34

company
id  name      acc_manager
1   company1  12
2   company2  23
3   company3  34
4   company4  34
5   company5  12
6   company6  0
```

I've tried to update using UPDATE and LIMIT like so

```
UPDATE client, company
SET client.acc_manager = 68, company.acc_manager = 68
WHERE company.id = client.companyid
  AND client.acc_manager = 34
  AND company.acc_manager = 34
LIMIT 55
```

but this resulted in the following error

**Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT**

so I tried updating the values of just one table using both tables in the WHERE clause but this outputted another error.

Is there any way I can update both tables, updating half of the items that match a criteria in the client table, and any related rows in the company table?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "but I only wish for half of the values of my client table to be updated including related data in my company table". There is no proper relation between your two tables, e.g. there is no consistent value for acc_manager across a company. So it is unclear which rows you want to update. MySQL would have the same problem, which is why you cannot update 2 tables at once and use limit. Could you explain which rows exactly should be updated in your sample set when you use "limit 5", and why? Based on this we may be able to write a/two proper queries, or fix the model.

Comment: My apologies. I would like the first half of values where client.acc_manager is 34 to be 68, and then update the company.acc_manager to 68 where client.companyid matches company.id where changes were made to client.acc_manager.

Comment: I would program that, not try to do in one single query.  But a better query builder might have a solution.  I would `1)` select clientid, companyid from client where acc_manager = 34.  `2)` this will give you a certain number of results.  Store that in an array (like in PHP for example). `3)` Cut the array in two `4)` using the first half, update client and set acc_manager = 68.  `5)` using the same first half, update company.acc_manager to 64 if the company id is in the array.

Comment: I was hoping there would be an easy MySQL solution, but doing what you suggested in PHP worked a treat. Thanks very much.